# How do I convert a column to a tuple in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I've a PIG question and is related to converting columns of tables into tuples so that I can pass them to a UDF. Details as follows:-

There is a result "C" which looks like following if I do "dump C"

(a1,b1,c1)
(a2,b2,c2)

I want to convert extract the every combination of 2 columns as follows:

(a1,a2,a3), (b1,b2,b3), (c1,c2,c3)

and then call a UDF on each possible pair of tuples:

UDF((a1,a2,a3), (b1,b2,b3))

UDF((a1,a2,a3), (c1,c2,c3))

UDF((c1,c2,c3), (b1,b2,b3))

How do I do this in PIG?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the values for a given "column" by using `GROUP .. ALL` and then using bag projection:

```
grpd = GROUP C ALL;
udfs =
    FOREACH grpd
    GENERATE
        UDF(grpd.a, grpd.b),
        UDF(grpd.a, grpd.c),
        UDF(grpd.c, grpd.b);
```

Note, however, that the values for each column will be stored in bags rather than tuples.  This is proper, because relations in Pig do not guarantee that the records are ordered in any particular way.  So your UDF should be comparing bags and not rely on the order of the elements.

However, it may be important that you be able to compare values that were originally in the same row; i.e., match up `a1` with `b1`, etc.  For this, you will need to write your UDF to take a single bag, with each tuple containing the paired elements `an` and `bn`.  To do this, use bag projection of two columns:

```
grpd = GROUP C ALL;
udfs =
    FOREACH grpd
    GENERATE
        UDF(grpd.(a,b)),
        UDF(grpd.(a,c)),
        UDF(grpd.(c,b));
```

Again, the tuples will not necessarily be in order, but you should not rely on that fact.  Your bag will contain the tuples `(a1,b1)`, `(a2,b2)`, etc.